# I want to buy some IPs

Tags: ip

I want to buy 256 Ips from a provider. How could I use them on my dedicated server?

Answer (score 12):

> I want to buy 256 Ips from a provider.

Sorry, can not do that. No one can. IP Addresses are not sold, they are assigned for use. Same way you don't own a telephone number. So, factually you never BUY them.  That would indicate ownership.

Talk to your provider about how to get IP addresses. THEY (!) have to handle it.

Basically you fill out a form by your local IP registry saying what you need and why.  Your provider then assigns you the addresses from their contingent or not (depending how good / bad / stupid you were arguing that you really do need 256 addresses).

In general, what you WANT is irrelevant, only what you NEED has relevance. Saying "I need an ip address per website" is equivalent to saying "I am too stupid to congfigure a web server properly", so you dont get what you need (because host headers have to be used according to guidelines).

Server admin 101: Network configuration.

In general, TALK TO YOUR PROVIDER.

Comment: @maz we got ya, you wanted to sell them in a few months, when the number of available IPv4 is close to zero ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: you live in Mongolia, you plan to get a block of IPs that are not associated with your country, (and you have rights for that - like offshore company etc):

You get a block of IPs for your needs, then you ask your provider to deliver those IPs to his hardware using BGP protocol, then your provider should change his routing to enable you to use this IPs. You use the IPs, IP2Country database has those IPs identified with your (not your provider) information.

Case 2: you just want to have 256 IPs available at your provider network:

You ask your provider for the service, he provides you with additional IPs (charging, for example, $1/monthly per IP).

Answer (score 0):

About the only way to really do that would be to buy a company that has a legacy "swamp" allocation.  I believe these addresses are in the range 192.0.0.0/8 and 198.0.0.0/8, as well as some others.  You'd basically need to search the [list published by ARIN](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml), and find a company to buy that holds an allocation.  My understanding according to ARIN rules is that you can't just buy the addresses, or they will revoke the legacy allocation, but I don't know that this has ever been tested.

There is, of course, a precedent for buying a company and keeping it's allocation, for example DEC was bought by HP, BBN was bought by, eventually, Level-3, etc...

If you just want an allocation, without literally buying it, speak to your provider and prepare to submit an ARIN justification to them supporting your request for 256 addresses.